# Wierd C++ vector error? In file included from c++/4.7.2/vector:70:0

Tags: c++, vector, openmpi

I am getting something like:

```
[jiewmeng@JM Assignment 2]$ mpic++ basketball-match.cpp -o basketball-match && mpirun -np 12 basketball-match
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/vector:70:0,
                 from basketball-match.cpp:4:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/vector.tcc: In instantiation of ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int [2]; _Alloc = std::allocator<int [2]>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int (*)[2], std::vector<int [2]> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = int (*)[2]]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:893:4:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = int [2]; _Alloc = std::allocator<int [2]>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = int [2]]’
basketball-match.cpp:145:49:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/vector.tcc:327:19: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/vector.tcc:333:4: error: invalid array assignment
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_tree.h:64,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/map:60,
                 from /usr/include/openmpi/ompi/mpi/cxx/mpicxx.h:38,
                 from /usr/include/mpi.h:2087,
                 from basketball-match.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int [2]; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = int (*)[2]]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ext/alloc_traits.h:202:9:   required from ‘static void __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::pointer, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int [2]; _Alloc = std::allocator<int [2]>; __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::pointer = int (*)[2]]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_vector.h:885:6:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = int [2]; _Alloc = std::allocator<int [2]>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = int [2]]’
basketball-match.cpp:145:49:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ext/new_allocator.h:120:9: error: parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]
```

Source can be found on **[GitHub](https://gist.github.com/4039617#file_basketball_match.cpp)**. What might be the cause?

Comment: I'd paste the code, that causes the error. A few people will follow the link and will look at your whole code, which is not short.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
vector<int[2]> playersAtBall;
```

The type of the vector element must be copy-constructible. An array is not. So you can't have a `vector<int[2]>`. You could wrap your array into a copy constructible struct, or use `std::pair<int, int>` instead.

If you have C++11 compiler you can use `std::array<int,2>`, as mfontanini point out in the comment. If you don't, but are willing to use boost, you can use `boost::array<int, 2>`